# Change root view controller and dismiss all view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have an application in which if I already have a user's `facebookUID` saved, I present them with the `MainViewController` and set it as the `rootViewController`, and if not, I present them with the `LoginViewController` as the `rootViewController` in my `AppDelegate.swift` file.

Inside the `MainViewController`, there is a `SettingsViewController` screen that I present modally. Inside that settings screen I have a logout button.

My question is, how can set the `rootViewController` as the `LoginViewController`, and dismiss all the other controllers in the stack when they click the logout button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it, in essence, exactly the same way you do it in the app delegate. But you are *not* in the app delegate, so you have to get there in steps:

1. From the UIApplication class you can get a reference to the `shared` application object.
2. From there you can get the app's `delegate`.
3. From there you can get the app delegate's `window`.
4. Now you can set the window's `rootViewController`.

The view controller that *was* the root view controller will vanish in a puff of smoke, along with all its dependent view controllers.

(This, however, is not quite how *I* would do it. I would have a stable root view controller whose only job is to be custom parent view controller to either the LoginViewController or the MainViewController. I'm not fond of the idea of changing root view controller's in the middle of the app. Still, it's not illegal.)

Comment: I liked your idea of the stable view controller. Just set it up and got it working. It's a much cleaner solution IMO. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, glad you liked it. It's a flexible solution because, as a custom parent view controller, you are in charge of the transition animation when switching between child view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You can switch to Login screen with animation. Also no risk of retaining the old viewcontrollers hierarchy

```
if let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {

        UIView.transition(with: appWindow!,
                          duration: 0.6,
                          options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight,
                          animations: {
                            let loginVC = LoginVC.init(nibName: "LoginVC", bundle: nil)
                            appWindow?.rootViewController = loginVC
        },
                          completion: nil)
    }
```